# How to call Nunjucks configuration file into my main app.js

Tags: express, nunjucks

Within my Express 4.17.1 app, I have the following template setup (below). I have read sources on pulling out routes into their own module files. But how can I take my nunjucks configuration code below and have it called into my app.js as a separate file **and still use my template filters**? Just trying to unclutter.

Thanks!

**App.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
const env = new nunjucks.Environment();
const path = require('path');

//...other stuff...

// VIEWS | NUNJUCKS
app.set('view engine', 'njk');
app.set('views', [path.join(__dirname, 'views'), path.join(__dirname, 'views/shared/')]);

// NUNJUCKS - CONFIGURATION & CUSTOM FILTERS
function setUpNunjucks(expressApp) {
    const env = nunjucks.configure([path.join(__dirname, 'views'), path.join(__dirname, 'views/shared/')], {
        autoescape: true, //default
        throwOnUndefined: true, //for dev testing only
        trimBlocks: true,
        lstripBlocks: true,
        noCache: false, //default
        express: app
    });

    //custom Nunjucks filter to pass back into template!
    env.addFilter('shorten', function (str, count) {
        return str.slice(0, count || 5);
    });

    //an object looper.  then do stuff with it
    //apply the following inside the template form
    env.addFilter('param', function (obj, mparam) {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
            //example of whatever is needed...
            if (mparam == value.param) {
                return `${value.value}`;
            }
        }
    });
}

setUpNunjucks(app);

//...other stuff...

//LISTEN
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Sever started on port ${PORT}`);
});
```